# Pulling a subset of wildcard tables using CURRENT_DATE()

Tags: sql, datetime, select, google-bigquery, where-clause

I have a set of tables all ending with the same string type date format, e.g.

```
response_logs.tablename_20200827
response_logs.tablename_20200826
response_logs.tablename_20200825
```

My query is structured to pull all of these tables in the same line using the Wildcard functionality:

```
SELECT
column1, column2, column3
FROM
response_logs.tablename_*
```

This has worked for a long time, but now the dataset is getting too large to pull the entire set. I would like to be able to pull just the last weeks' worth of data, based on the current date. I've had success with manually setting the table suffix date:

```
SELECT
column1, column2, column3
FROM 
response_logs.tablename_*
WHERE _table_suffix>"20200824"
```

but I would like to be able to automate this process (the query is scheduled and runs without me watching it usually). Something like:

```
SELECT
column1, column2, column3
FROM
response_logs.tablename_*
WHERE _table_suffix>(CURRENT_DATE()-7)
```

How do I format the (CURRENT_DATE()) section of the query so that it only pulls the last weeks' worth of tables?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it works with date arithmetics and `FOMAT_DATE()`?

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM `response_logs.tablename_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX >= FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 7 DAY))
```

Note that the documentation recommends surrounding the table name and the wildcard with backticks, I modified the query accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Subtract days to get your time window, and then format the date in the same format as the suffix.

```
select _table_suffix as suffix, count(*) as ct
from `project.dataset.table_*`
where _table_suffix >= format_date('%Y%m%d', date_sub(current_date(), interval 7 day))
group by 1
```